# Compling program in linux without a ./configure or makefile

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have downloaded Nexus-4.1.6.tar.gz from here https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/nexus/releases

I unzipped it to my home folder, but I can't figure out how to compile it.

folder directory:
CMakelist.txt
doc/
html/
LICENCE
README.md
README.txt
src/

common/
  nxsbuild/
  nxsedit/
  nxsview/
  nxszip/

These contain .ccp and .h files

I can't find a ./configure or a make.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: whats in `Cmakelist.txt`? No hints in the READMEs? Else ask the ower on `git`? Good luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7859663/841108 is a near duplicate

Comment: BTW, you should propose a patch to their `README.md` stating to use `cmake` for build

Comment: Cmakeist contains: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1) project(nexus)  add_subdirectory(src/nxsbuild)  add_subdirectory(src/nxsedit)  add_subdirectory(src/nxsview)  and thank you for who ever marked it down, explaining I need to use CMAKE would have been far more constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CMake and create platform-specific build format, in your case (linux) a Makefile.

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain how I do this?

Comment: I tried mkdie build-dir then cd build-dir and then cmake .. but I get a long list of errors:
CMake Warning at src/nxsbuild/CMakeLists.txt:53 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

Comment: As your error says, you need Qt5 dependencies installed in your system: Install them using for example `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls`.
Looking into the project [readme](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/nexus/blob/master/README.md) file, at the bottom says that Qt and VCG libraries are required. You'll need to download them and fit evetything in order to create the _makefile_ properly. Don't bother changing folder names as the repository is not properly documented and paths to inside the CMakeLists.txt can be significantly improved.