# Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_freopen referenced in function qh_initflags

Tags: c++, runtime-error, point-cloud-library, open3d

I am using Visual Studio to run this code.  https://gist.github.com/UnaNancyOwen/731238a6a5c916a28e43731494d1d2cb.
I get these three errors while compiling.

1. Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_freopen referenced in function qh_initflags
2. Error   LNK2005 qh_fprintf already defined in qhullstatic_d.lib(userprintf.obj)
3. Error LNK1120   1 unresolved externals

Can anyone please help me? [enter image description here][1]

Comment: Exactly how are you running the code?? I think that there are issues with your build configurations. [Here is a thread on how to use CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859623/how-do-i-use-cmake).

Comment: @brc-dd I copied .cpp, .h, and CMakeLists.txt files and made .sln file using CMake GUI. I already did the steps mentioned on that thread. When I try to build the project, it gives me those errors.