# How to generate c++ grpc file after installing it by vcpkg and cmake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, grpc, vcpkg

I install grpc by `vcpkg install grpc` and add it to cmake file .
Now I want to generate grpc c++ file , I run :

```
protoc --cpp_out=grpc_file/ --grpc_out=grpc_file/  --proto_path=grpc_proto/  ./grpc_proto/side_information.proto
```

It returns error :

```
protoc-gen-grpc: program not found or is not executable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

What should I do to use the grpc_cpp_plugin installed by vcpkg ?
My workspace is :

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Readme.md
├── build
├── build_envs.sh
├── grpc_file
├── grpc_proto
├── main.cpp
├── twitter.json
└── vcpkg
```

Comment: I understand that this is not the answer you are looking for, but please try bazel/cmake https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/cpp#grpc-c if you are having trouble with vcpkg. Bazel/CMake is what the gRPC devs use

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64404450/compile-grpc-c-examples-with-vcpkg It's not same, but might help you to see if you are missing some packages

Comment: Can you also show your configuration in CMake

Comment: @DachuanZhao Was my answer helpful, or do you need more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your CMakeLists.txt like below?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

if(DEFINED ENV{VCPKG_ROOT})
    set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE $ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
else()
    set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/path_to_vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
endif()

project(Foo)

find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

...

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Bar})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE gRPC::gpr gRPC::grpc gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc_cronet)
```

In the Folder path_to_vcpkg/packages/grpc_x64-PLATFORM/tools/grpc you will find all the precompiled grpc-plugins for your platform (also grpc_cpp_plugin).

Comment: Like this . My CMakeLists.txt contains ```set(VCPKG_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")``` . I find it . Thanks~

Answer (score 4):

The protoc is trying to look for the `protoc-gen-grpc` plugin from your `PATH`, but it is unable to find one, thus the error. The fix is to simply specify the path to the said plugin. Given that you are using `vcpkg`, that path is probably something along these lines:

```
protoc --cpp_out=grpc_file/ --grpc_out=grpc_file/ --proto_path=grpc_proto/ \
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="<vcpkg_install_path>\packages\grpc_x64-windows\tools\grpc\grpc_cpp_plugin.exe" \ 
./grpc_proto/side_information.proto
```

If you are looking to be using Visual Studio for your grpc project, I recommend checking out [this guide](https://sanoj.in/2020/05/07/working-with-grpc-in-windows.html) for generating a VS solution among other things.

Comment: Was looking for this executable for ages - thanks

Comment: For future reference, how did you locate this executable - I couldn't find it in any docs?