# '--grpc_out' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: grpc

add_custom_command(
OUTPUT "${hw_proto_srcs}" "${hw_proto_hdrs}" "${hw_grpc_srcs}" "${hw_grpc_hdrs}"
COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
--cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
-I "${hw_proto_path}"
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="D:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin"
"${hw_proto}"
DEPENDS "${hw_proto}")
I got this error

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66591301/609290). You will need `protoc` and a plugin for gRPC (to prove `--grpc_out`). I think you're missing the latter.

Comment: "provide" not "prove"