# How can I solve my problem with compiling cpp code include matplotlibcpp.h?

Tags: python, c++, windows, compilation, g++

I installed Python 3.8.18 and downloaded matplotlibcpp.h file from this [ripo](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp)
I coded in windows and I could not install matplotlib through vcpkg.

My CPP code is:

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    matplotlibcpp::plot({1,3,2,4});
    matplotlibcpp::show();
    return 0;
}
```

I copy matplotlibcpp.h in the same folder with code.
I tried to compile code through g++ compiler with the command bellow:

```
g++ main.cpp -o out -I C:\python\include -I C:\python\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy
```

and I got error in bellow:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
matplotlibcpp.h: In constructor 'matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter()':
matplotlibcpp.h:174:31: warning: 'void Py_SetProgramName(const wchar_t*)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  174 |         Py_SetProgramName(name);
      |                               ^
In file included from C:\python\include/Python.h:94,
                 from matplotlibcpp.h:5,
                 from main.cpp:1:
C:\python\include/pylifecycle.h:37:38: note: declared here
   37 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) PyAPI_FUNC(void) Py_SetProgramName(const wchar_t *);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:
matplotlibcpp.h:174:31: warning: 'void Py_SetProgramName(const wchar_t*)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  174 |         Py_SetProgramName(name);
      |                               ^
In file included from C:\python\include/Python.h:94,
                 from matplotlibcpp.h:5,
                 from main.cpp:1:
C:\python\include/pylifecycle.h:37:38: note: declared here
   37 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) PyAPI_FUNC(void) Py_SetProgramName(const wchar_t *);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:
matplotlibcpp.h:182:57: warning: 'void PySys_SetArgv(int, wchar_t**)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  182 |         PySys_SetArgv(argc, const_cast<wchar_t **>(argv));
      |                                                         ^
In file included from C:\python\include/Python.h:96,
                 from matplotlibcpp.h:5,
                 from main.cpp:1:
C:\python\include/sysmodule.h:13:38: note: declared here
   13 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PySys_SetArgv(int, wchar_t **);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:
matplotlibcpp.h:182:57: warning: 'void PySys_SetArgv(int, wchar_t**)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  182 |         PySys_SetArgv(argc, const_cast<wchar_t **>(argv));
      |                                                         ^
In file included from C:\python\include/Python.h:96,
                 from matplotlibcpp.h:5,
                 from main.cpp:1:
C:\python\include/sysmodule.h:13:38: note: declared here
   13 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PySys_SetArgv(int, wchar_t **);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_ImportModule'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCapsule_Type'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCapsule_GetPointer'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x232): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x289): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2ae): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2e6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter11safe_importEP7_objectNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter11safe_importEP7_objectNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x23): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter11safe_importEP7_objectNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter11safe_importEP7_objectNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0xc9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFunction_Type'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter12import_numpyEv[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter12import_numpyEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Print'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter12import_numpyEv[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter12import_numpyEv]+0x1d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter12import_numpyEv[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreter12import_numpyEv]+0x2f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x4c): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_SetProgramName'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x53): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x8b): undefined reference to `_imp__PySys_SetArgv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0xa6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0xb7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0xc8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0xd9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x138): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_Import'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x188): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x198): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Print'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x20b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_CallMethod'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x218): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_Import'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x268): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x2b5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_Import'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x30e): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x365): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_Import'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x3b5): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x1a54): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x1ae0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x1b01): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterC1Ev]+0x1b7a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterD1Ev[__ZN13matplotlibcpp6detail12_interpreterD1Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb]+0x34): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_CallObject'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb]+0x43): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb]+0x4d): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_FalseStruct'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb]+0x64): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItemString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb]+0x8c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Call'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb]+0xdc): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4showEb]+0x169): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x6a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x7b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x9a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0xb6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0xd2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0xeb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_CallObject'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x13b): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DEHGHA~2.KCR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTTMRIo.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[__ZN13matplotlibcpp4plotIddEEbRKSt6vectorIT_SaIS2_EERKS1_IT0_SaIS7_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x191): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I solve this in Windows?

Comment: You got a bunch of warnings and then a bunch of linker errors. The linker errors are caused by you not linking with the library that contains the missing names `Py_Dealloc`, `PyObject_CallObject` etc. Do those names mean anything to you?

Comment: It seems like you include a few python libs but don't link to any. Including a header from some large open source library usually requires you to link to a library. In msvc there is a `#pragma comment (lib, libname)` that can force linking with just a header but MinGW does not use it.

Comment: ***I copy matplotlibcpp.h in the same folder with code.*** That is wrong. It's not that simple to use a library. For this particular library you needed to use CMake to generate a Makefile and compile the project and use the libraries that were generated.

Comment: @drescherjm How can I link them in the makefile? May please guide me? Should I install new tool?

Comment: The Makefile is to generate the library(ies) you need to link. See this answer for the general instruction on how to use CMake to generate a Makefile in most projects: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7859663/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7859663/487892)

Answer (score 0):

It was problem by linking python lib with mingw.
I use MSYS2 instead of other and my problem solved through this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

and I copile with bellow command:

```
g++ main.cpp -I C:\Python310\include -I C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -L C:\Python310\libs -lpython310
```